# How do I get rid of the vertical scrollbar of a textarea in IE?

Tags: html, css, textarea, scrollbar

There is a nasty right-side inactive scrollbar in the textarea in IE, in FF the textarea is clean. How to make it clean in IE as well?

Comment: Could you provide an example (link, print screen)?

Comment: @Jerome: use your imagination?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Quick experimentation suggests that IE6 and IE8 (unable to test 7 at the moment) both honor the auto value for overflow. Thus, to make the scroll bars appear when necessary, but hidden when not, add the following style rule:

```
textarea { overflow: auto; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the overflow: auto style to only apply scrollbars when needed

```
textarea { overflow: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Landed here initially but the suggested property

```
textarea { overflow: auto; }
```

didn't work for me, so I checked a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1210078/1000257) and got [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1210102/1000257) that worked fine

```
textarea { overflow-y: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use to remove disable scroll bar in textarea.

```
textarea {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```