# How to disable default scroll bar for textareas in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am going through some of my older sites where I have a contact form and in IE8 there always is a vertical scroll bar displayed for my textareas, even when there is no content.

In Firefox, it doesn't seem to make the vertical scroll bar exist until the content in the textarea reaches a height that deems them necessary.

I have styled my input boxes on my older sites, and a scroll bar appearing by default makes them look quite ugly.

My question, is there anything I can do about this, or is it just a default IE8 behaviour?

I've tried setting `overflow: auto` but it has not worked.

Comment: That's weird.  Are you looking for a CSS solution, or perhaps jscript?

Comment: CSS preferably ... but JS if I *must*

Comment: Have you tried overflow: hidden, as mentioned below?

Comment: I think that would stop people from being able to scroll at all... and if they enter more text than the height of the textarea, that could be a problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can't test on IE8 right now, but I can tell you that this works in IE6:

```
textarea {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use overflow: hidden and all will be well.

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <textarea rows="10" style="overflow: hidden;"/>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: That would make it very difficult for the user if they enter more text than can fit in the visible area.

Comment: Bad solution. This hides text and will probably confuse the user.
Also, what standard does your tag soup follow?

Comment: I assumed the OP just wished the scroll bar to not be there at all... my bad!

Comment: I for one like this one better when I'm using textarea autoresizer (there are jQuery plugins out there). In that case JS makes sure textarea grows along with content. However, sometimes these plugins aren't pixel-perfect and scrollbars appear when they shouldn't on 1-line situation in IE. So overflow: auto doesn't solve the problem there, but overflow:hidden does. +1 here then. (I imagine that JS autoresizer may be an issue on less popular browser it wasn't tested with thoroughly, e.g. mobile, in which case large amount of text in such a TEXTAREA might actually get hidden...)